# Clojure - Unable to parse json in response's body

Tags: json, clojure

I'm having an issue parsing the json that came in a response's body... I can successfully get the value from the body. However, when I'm trying to get some value from the json in the body, I'm unable to.

This is the function I'm using:

```
(ns cs4261-server.handler
  (:use compojure.core)
  (:require [compojure.handler :as handler]
            [compojure.route :as route]
            [clojure.data.json :as json]
            [ring.util.response :as resp]
            [org.httpkit.client :as http]
            [clj-http.client :as client]
            [org.httpkit.server :as hs]
            [ring.middleware.json :refer [wrap-json-params]]
            [ring.middleware.jsonp :refer [wrap-json-with-padding]]))

(defn get-recipes [param]
  (let [req (str "http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipes?_app_id=78dccce1&_app_key=87460fca330c28f52a9603ababd5a54f&allowedCourse[]=course^course-Dinner&maxTotalTimeInSeconds=3600&" param)]
    (let [resp (client/get req)]
      (let [body (json/read-str (get resp :body))]
        (get body :matches)))))

(defroutes app-routes
  (GET "/" [] (json/write-str "This is just some start screen to appease myself."}))
  (GET "/somerecipe" {params :query-string} (get-recipes params))
  (GET "/recipes" [] (json/write-str { :message "This is some other different response"}))
  (route/resources "/")
  (route/not-found "This isn't the page you're looking for.."))
```

And I get this when I run `(keys body)`: `attributiontotalMatchCountfacetCountsmatchescriteria`

`(vals body)` gets me:

```
{"html" "Recipe search powered by Yummly", "url" "http://www.yummly.com/recipes/", "text" "Recipe search powered by Yummly", "logo" "http://static.yummly.com/api-logo.png"}73458{}[{"ingredients" ["fresh basil" "green onions" "mayo" "grated parmesan cheese" "salt" "ground black pepper" "cooked chicken"], "totalTimeInSeconds" 2700.0, "sourceDisplayName" "Kalyn's Kitchen", "flavors" nil, "attributes" {"course" ["Salads"]}, "imageUrlsBySize" {"90" "http://lh4.ggpht.com/xggeGxIgwVNoYmmiIRN36BubOH9rCY40mXh710HI2iMcq7LA3oRMR_9CxZPk-R_5RvolER9H5K8FmHv0gqItJyg=s90-c"}, "smallImageUrls" ["http://lh4.ggpht.com/e7-jniVWaIcn2_d5-hT5jR52w-zdTB6dUYNP2QNwDI1Y9kVRUotX-2y0BKEkWKtrMtxgHH2fjGv7_wchojr_=s90"], "recipeName" "Chicken Salad with Basil and Parmesan", "id" "Chicken-salad-with-basil-and-parmesan-309576", "rating" 5} {"ingredients" ["dried breadcrumbs" "grated parmesan cheese" "eggs" "boneless skinless chicken breasts" "italian seasoning"], "totalTimeInSeconds" 2700.0, "sourceDisplayName" "AllRecipes", "flavors" {"sour" 0.16666666666666666, "salty" 0.8333333333333334, "sweet" 0.16666666666666666, "bitter" 0.5, "meaty" 0.6666666666666666}, "attributes" {}, "imageUrlsBySize" {"90" "http://lh4.ggpht.com/wSztxHluA4QpWg2Ij1LZIMFXl2lcEW05W1VBbV8nIPHz7bDyjmIaemTsyCQ3yFSD4iMgYkvvpFUUWXoKcHI4rGg=s90-c"}, "smallImageUrls" ["http://lh5.ggpht.com/xKUecmTW7W9-8go_7SiStOl4weFo7XXeNdJF9soWJ6q0KHM8S3sMHRzEUiprkkSLBYp4cOHTuANFMj-_RALz2w=s90"], "recipeName" "Simply Parmesan Chicken", "id" "Simply-Parmesan-Chicken-Allrecipes", "rating" 5} {"ingredients" ["safflower oil" "onion" "kosher salt" "freshly ground pepper" "cooked chicken" "sweet paprika"], "totalTimeInSeconds" 3000.0, "sourceDisplayName" "Big Girls Small Kitchen", "flavors" {"sour" 0.3333333333333333, "salty" 0.16666666666666666, "sweet" 0.6666666666666666, "bitter" 0.16666666666666666, "piquant" 0.3333333333333333, "meaty" 0.16666666666666666}, "attributes" {}, "imageUrlsBySize" {"90" "http://lh3.ggpht.com/UxAXD4WzOGsSRbRH1MGq8BiiDJn-CQ95khtRooSe8vQL9ISciXr1vBxie2YCsrzdiwVd-Kf9IQ7YpGtk_zmBf1o=s90-c"}, "smallImageUrls" ["http://lh4.ggpht.com/CUG6ENZ5ZaOi-gbcTkFZ9A123PAzek15qTk53pHTVPnC1PH92O-ayqt4PDPgp_OycTTLVgU4m8e-Kv7daA7lcxs=s90"], "recipeName" "Chicken Fritz", "id" "Chicken-Fritz-466963", "rating" 5} {"ingredients" ["fresh mozzarella" "fresh basil" "olive oil" "salt" "tomatoes" "balsamic vinegar" "cooked chicken"], "totalTimeInSeconds" 900.0, "sourceDisplayName" "Steamy Kitchen", "flavors" {"sour" 0.3333333333333333, "salty" 1.0, "sweet" 0.5, "bitter" 0.8333333333333334, "meaty" 1.0}, "attributes" {}, "imageUrlsBySize" {"90" "http://lh5.ggpht.com/MxMrfdlGI8sXJK0lLp3g-Y_FpJrx0JI3zx06jOMf_YUkLUzdDFNR-c7KKiwE10xP5PksrSsjcvf7qphDApWT=s90-c"}, "smallImageUrls" ["http://lh6.ggpht.com/YV6IbDkZqbl2dEd-s6yRU0qnXyUM3_QWimLHkqILnHg14w7ysKjdELus7EhvHq4QfW0QD1IPELMzJGXyOl3bdw=s90"], "recipeName" "Chicken Caprese", "id" "Chicken-Caprese-512479", "rating" 5} {"ingredients" ["coarse salt" "boneless chicken breast halves" "kalamata" "grape tomatoes" "olive oil" "capers" "freshly ground pepper"], "totalTimeInSeconds" 1800.0, "sourceDisplayName" "Martha Stewart", "flavors" {"sour" 1.0, "salty" 0.3333333333333333, "sweet" 0.8333333333333334, "bitter" 0.6666666666666666, "meaty" 0.16666666666666666}, "attributes" {"cuisine" ["mediterranean"]}, "imageUrlsBySize" {"90" "http://lh4.ggpht.com/hYtmp4SgiNq_OXhEz5D_WdjiBZYFcX3FXDcw0Pi_0G6PPC10rwVHCRoFfWO3Qy2jofDarFyJd2djy1OKmv8smRE=s90-c"}, "smallImageUrls" ["http://lh5.ggpht.com/2iliWjEertg18obLCM8hxQVCSme-rkazLrtp1lp_L9TzO7bwcSw83sLjOP5JxErrCyfdJQcw8nm6DwgPyruU-Q=s90"], "recipeName" "Mediterranean Chicken", "id" "Mediterranean-Chicken-Martha-Stewart", "rating" 5} {"ingredients" ["smoked paprika" "garlic salt" "meat" "boneless chicken skinless thigh" "extra-virgin olive oil"], "totalTimeInSeconds" 2700.0, "sourceDisplayName" "The Shiksa in the Kitchen", "flavors" nil, "attributes" {}, "imageUrlsBySize" {"90" "http://lh5.ggpht.com/c1WyAP36fwSxoaarTbNsx_AgGygEIw5Kz1BUoKoTYvbaVcvr_M4h4TYnW9J697_RN2Jy537lIsuTzS7mwPoGZg=s90-c"}, "smallImageUrls" ["http://lh4.ggpht.com/B1ldEB7Dsj8r45FYUMZmxFdybJN_eBc4rt2rxIbaCaMH8GpKVk97xzaiMbEDgSKDbKkrHVLUs6RPM6rKxjV_=s90"], "recipeName" "Smoked Paprika Chicken", "id" "Smoked-Paprika-Chicken-The-Shiksa-in-the-Kitchen-200675", "rating" 5} {"ingredients" ["cabbage" "flour" "fresh tomatoes" "lemon wedge" "eggs" "panko breadcrumbs" "vegetable oil" "salt" "tonkatsu sauce" "chicken breasts"], "totalTimeInSeconds" 3000.0, "sourceDisplayName" "Food Republic", "flavors" {"sour" 0.6666666666666666, "salty" 0.16666666666666666, "sweet" 0.16666666666666666, "bitter" 0.16666666666666666, "meaty" 0.8333333333333334}, "attributes" {}, "imageUrlsBySize" {"90" "http://lh5.ggpht.com/xKpWqdnK3BhVeiZG0Zg9FB12WVM_O7KXxlDE1S_uuArRooIFHvAYZIipmmdrh8tMgGqtUS_fb2utpzdq7V1Bbg=s90-c"}, "smallImageUrls" ["http://lh3.ggpht.com/fasJj35yJTUk1jZtrlwEGskqw5EpUN212J7U47vNHjic4C8uq6TXGOqqKKIp9qWvuHYgBKgn4YQdER36lzEnxQ=s90"], "recipeName" "Chicken Katsu", "id" "Chicken-Katsu-561368", "rating" 4} {"ingredients" ["soy sauce" "pineapple juice" "garlic powder" "brown sugar" "boneless skinless chicken breasts" "bourbon whiskey" "ground black pepper"], "totalTimeInSeconds" 1800.0, "sourceDisplayName" "AllRecipes", "flavors" {"sour" 0.3333333333333333, "salty" 0.8333333333333334, "sweet" 0.8333333333333334, "bitter" 0.3333333333333333, "meaty" 0.16666666666666666}, "attributes" {}, "imageUrlsBySize" {"90" "http://lh4.ggpht.com/D31Ftoc_U4gvv2U3ZmKV_K6d5GREXJI4IzdCzYRi5Q8MrvdzO9uvkVnIhRZfMvG1ywGi4rLq93wHcyXKTWobOFE=s90-c"}, "smallImageUrls" ["http://lh3.ggpht.com/cCDQ7v9da78XI_ITjktEkf0cxV4G-ddNVJ6WQcJVFoRjv3SzIv2g03R-99Qgm8bLl3uDnPwyRsbzooCdGngEcA=s90"], "recipeName" "Whiskey Chicken", "id" "Whiskey-Chicken-Allrecipes", "rating" 4} {"ingredients" ["fish sauce" "bibb lettuce" "fresh lime juice" "fresh cilantro" "water" "ground chicken" "yellow onion"], "totalTimeInSeconds" 1800.0, "sourceDisplayName" "Food Republic", "flavors" {"sour" 0.3333333333333333, "salty" 0.6666666666666666, "sweet" 0.16666666666666666, "bitter" 0.3333333333333333, "meaty" 0.6666666666666666}, "attributes" {}, "imageUrlsBySize" {"90" "http://lh5.ggpht.com/PQwNMMmYfYU3ux62Kuy8ag8TBdqyg1AG5gW9gKO_oxk1WtmJar-RMGIBGsHndI-ynsOSVoJWspuotGp3uKf6=s90-c"}, "smallImageUrls" ["http://lh5.ggpht.com/JA3sOmAMrrvdUAS3qpDVdxjtBPElJHuAxdZZs1jfbLs0RNVEBYvz7FsCaAEhCCZRgHzJBh6Iuh7rFMv-9DWf2bc=s90"], "recipeName" "Easy Chicken Lettuce Wraps", "id" "Easy-Chicken-Lettuce-Wraps-513151", "rating" 5} {"ingredients" ["baby spinach leaves" "shredded mozzarella cheese" "kosher salt" "white onion" "extra-virgin olive oil" "ground black pepper" "chicken breasts" "bow-tie pasta" "Philadelphia Cooking Creme" "minced garlic"], "totalTimeInSeconds" 3600.0, "sourceDisplayName" "Picky Palate", "flavors" {"sour" 0.16666666666666666, "salty" 0.16666666666666666, "sweet" 0.16666666666666666, "bitter" 0.16666666666666666, "meaty" 0.6666666666666666}, "attributes" {}, "imageUrlsBySize" {"90" "http://lh5.ggpht.com/oeLx_E9OmzThj-VGPmXCLQ2U2SHsMqzn3pY0WMfsom1FMA2dhU_HCCJ4x-UjM0CfuZVrtlQlG317JTL4iSlV9A=s90-c"}, "smallImageUrls" ["http://lh5.ggpht.com/NQIgfnIrP-31XEvU5V6Pz9xgVHO0xcD2PmYZsqq9x_-mmayQHBBMLQQj4vC3VFnBM61tbilMtg_8-sw23kqwPg=s90"], "recipeName" "Chicken Florentine Bowtie Pasta", "id" "Chicken-florentine-bowtie-pasta-334939", "rating" 5}]{"excludedIngredients" nil, "allowedIngredients" nil, "terms" nil}
```

So with both keys and vals there, I should be able to get something, but I'm not. Any ideas?

Comment: The keys might be strings. Does `(get body "matches")` work?

Comment: That sadly gives me a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException Key must be integer` error.

Comment: The keys are indeed strings. What is `client`? What parameter are you calling get-recipes with? Your code works fine if I do `(get body "matches")` with "cheese" as an parameter.

Comment: I've updated it to include the what I'm requiring and where the function is being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `:key-fn keyword` to `json/read-str` in order to get keyword keys.
And then you can query map for :matches with `(get body :matches)` or even `(:matches body)`

Here is example REPL session:

```
(require '[clojure.data.json :as json])

(def js
  (json/read-str "{\"a\": 7, \"b\": 13}"
                 :key-fn keyword))
(:a js)

;; Gives back 7
```

Or without `key-fn`:

```
(def js
  (json/read-str "{\"a\": 7, \"b\": 13}"))

;; Keys are strings now, have to use (get map key)
(get js "a")

;; Gives back 7
```

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to have done the trick! Without `key-fn` didn't work for me, so I'll have to remember to include it from now on.